# Is there a difference between .split(" ") vs .split()

Tags: python, split

Is there a fundamental difference between `.split(' ')` vs `.split()` in python?
I believe `.split()`'s default value is blank space so the two should be the same but i get different results on hackerrank.

Comment: Remember to check the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) if you're confused by a method's behavior.

Comment: You have to check the api documentation for split methods for string. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-string-split/

Answer (score 11):

As per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) (for Python 3.8, and with my emphasis):

> If `sep` is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting algorithm is applied: ***runs of consecutive whitespace*** are regarded as a ***single*** separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.

So, no, they are not the same thing. For example (note there are *two* spaces between `A` and `B` and one at the start and end):

```
>>> s = " A  B "
>>> s.split()
['A', 'B']
>>> s.split(" ")
['', 'A', '', 'B', '']
```

Additionally, consecutive whitespace means *any* whitespace characters, not just spaces:

```
>>> s = " A\t  \t\n\rB "
>>> s.split()
['A', 'B']
>>> s.split(" ")
['', 'A\t', '', '\t\n\rB', '']
```

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> print ''.split.__doc__
S.split([sep [,maxsplit]]) -> list of strings

Return a list of the words in the string S, using sep as the
delimiter string.  If maxsplit is given, at most maxsplit
splits are done. If sep is not specified or is None, any
whitespace string is a separator and empty strings are removed
from the result.
```

Answer (score 2):

Documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) for `str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)`. Note:

> If sep is not specified or is None, a different splitting algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace. Consequently, splitting an empty string or a string consisting of just whitespace with a None separator returns [].

```py
>>> a = " hello world "
>>> a.split(" ")
['', 'hello', 'world', '']
>>> a.split()
['hello', 'world']

>>> b = "hello           world"
>>> b.split(" ")
['hello', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'world']
>>> b.split()
['hello', 'world']

>>> c = "       "
>>> c.split(" ")
['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '']
>>> c.split()
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

As clearly mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

> If `sep` is not specified or is `None`, a different splitting
>   algorithm is applied: runs of consecutive whitespace are regarded as a
>   single separator, and the result will contain no empty strings at the
>   start or end if the string has leading or trailing whitespace.